# After turning on CSM, monitor has no signal and keyboard lights turn off

Tags: motherboard, bios

I recently managed to change my BIOS boot options. I turned on CSM (Compatibility Support Module), didn't read the CMS options and saved and exited from there. (I wanted to try to install Windows 7, which stuck at "Starting Windows.")

Now, when I power on, my PC's monitor says no signal, then goes black. My keyboard's lights (Num Lock, Caps Lock and Scroll Lock) light up at the beginning but after some time they disappear. Now I can't even get in BIOS to change CSM.

My computer has a warranty, and I wanted to ask, is it possible to reset BIOS settings to default without violating that warranty? Or, maybe, should I try to use a VGA cable for the monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset to factory default (using the jumper or switch on the motherboard, check the manual for exact procedure) will never invalidate the warranty.

In general: When changing bios operational mode (uefi to legacy or vice-versa, csm on/off) you should always do a reset to bios defaults BEFORE saving the settings.
Some of the settings in the bios may change meaning during such a switch. A reset to defaults will make sure they have sane values.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tonny, for your answer. But I have stickers on my pc box, so when I open it up they will break. It is computer at my work. So I should call a tech support to do this instead of me to save the warranty? I also wanted to try to use VGA cable, may be monitor will show something or type of cable does not matter?

Comment: @Zeolite Work computer ? Why did you try to install another OS anyway ? That is why there is an IT department. For all I know just installing another OS will cause licensing issues and/or compliance problems. In a work-environment this is NOT something you can play around with.